# assigning model to tableview and creating rows and columns

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am New to Qt creator .
I want to create a table View with 1 row and 2 columns using QmodelIndex.
There was an error in assigning the model to the tableView and creating data .

```
QTableView* const tableView
            = { htca_ui->tableView,
                 };

    tableView->setModel(&mymodel);
```

How to create a model and assign to the view to create the row with 2 columns using QmodelIndex?

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

If you have added a tableView with the UI designer you don't need to create it again in code. Assuming your QTableView is called tableView and that htca_ui is your UI pointer, you can do

```
htca_ui->tableView->setModel(&mymodel);
```

Edit : And it occurs to me the &mymodel means you're creating it on the stack, which may not be the best idea. Better to do :

```
MyModel *mymodelinstance = new MyModel(this);
htca_ui->tableView->setModel(mymodelinstance);
```

However: the model classes can be complex to work with. If you are just after a simple table with minimum code, I would suggest using a QTableWidget rather than a QTableView. Add a QTableWidget to your UI, then you can do

```
htca_ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(1);
htca_ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2);
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem("An Item");
htca_ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0, item); // The item at the top left will read "An Item".
```

See the documentation for [QTableWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qtablewidget.html) for more info